# Determine window pixel density with captureVisibleTab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I capture a tab with Chrome using `captureVisibleTab`, the pixels are double what I see with CMD+Shift+4 drag / Esc

How can I determine what the pixel density really is?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the pixel density using `window.devicePixelRatio` which returns 2 on my Macbook